# Generating Bootstrap Columns with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to make a little bit of a bootstrap layout for a Wordpress theme using Advanced Custom Fields. I have it set up at the moment, so if you have 2 fields of content, it generates a "6" width column. If you have 3 fields it generates a "4" field column instead.

```
<?php if(get_field('link_tiles')) : 

while (has_sub_field('link_tiles')) :

$number_of_cols = count(get_field( 'link_tiles' ));

if ($number_of_cols == 2) {
         echo '<div class="col-md-6" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">';
       }
       elseif ($number_of_cols >= 3) {
         echo '<div class="col-md-4" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">';
       }
?>
```

What I really want now though, is make it so if you have 4 fields entered, it generates 3x "4" width columns and then 1x "6" width column and then if you have 6 fields entered it goes back to generating "4" width columns. I imagine it would take some logic using a While Loop, but I can't quite figure out the logic of it. I'm quite new to PHP, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's tough to say without seeing the surrounding code, but you must already be iterating through the columns (echoing a `<div>` for each). Are you iterating through an Array? Is there already a variable set to the current index?

If so, the logic could be something like this, given $index equals the current column number:

```
// set default for two columns
$col_class = 'col-md-6';

if ($number_of_cols == 3) {
  $col_class = 'col-md-4';
} elseif ($number_of_cols == 4 && $index < 4) {
  $col_class = 'col-md-4';
} elseif ($number_of_cols == 4 && $index == 4) {
  $col_class = 'col-md-6';
}

echo '<div class="' . $col_class . '">';
```

Although it seems like if you have 4 columns, you really would want 4 columns of `.col-md-3` rather than 3 of `.col-md-4` and one of `.col-md-6` like you specify above (which would be a total of 18 columns; Bootstrap rows max out at 12 columns).

**Update:**

This is a bit pseudo-code, but hopefully gives you ideas on how to proceed. Note you still need to output content for each column, obviously.

```
<?php if(get_field('link_tiles')) :

    $number_of_cols = count(get_field( 'link_tiles' ));
    $counter = 1;

    while (has_sub_field('link_tiles')) : 
        // set default for two columns
        $col_class = 'col-md-6';

        if ($number_of_cols == 3) {
          $col_class = 'col-md-4';
        } elseif ($number_of_cols == 4 && $counter < 4) {
          $col_class = 'col-md-4';
        } elseif ($number_of_cols == 4 && $counter == 4) {
          $col_class = 'col-md-6';
        }

        echo '<div class="' . $col_class . '"></div>';

        // increment the counter for the next column
        $counter++;

    endwhile;

endif; ?>
```

Comment: I'm using the Advanced Custom Fields Repeater field plug in, so for each field I add a new Column is made.

I'll update the first post.

Comment: So are you using something like the Basic Loop listed here? http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/

Comment: That's right, yes. It counts the Rows of fields created.

Comment: Thank you Benjarwar, that's exactly what I was after!